# How do I pass my longitude and latitude variables to another function?

Tags: swift, xcode, function

I have the function "locationManager" where I create and set longitude and latitude. What I want to do is be able to get that location when the button is pushed. How can I get longitude and latitude into the @IBAction for when I press that button? Than you so much for your help!

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupLocationManager()
    }

    func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.last {
            if location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 {
                locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

                let longitude = location.coordinate.longitude
                let latitude = location.coordinate.latitude

                print("longitude = \(longitude)")
                print("latitude = \(latitude)")


            }
        }
    }


    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Location update failed, \(error)")
    }


    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // print(longitude)
    }

}
```

Comment: Without commenting on the architecture of your code; Whenever locationManager() is called, at the lines where your print() statements are, why not also store your values to a class variable so you can read out these in your buttonPressed()? So two vars right under your let locationManager = ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your location variable if class scope

```
fileprivate var mylocation:CLLocation?
```

set mylocation in

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.last {
            if location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 {
                locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

                myLocation = location
            }
        }
    }
```

now you can access location when button tap

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
                let longitude = myLocation.coordinate.longitude
                let latitude = myLocation.coordinate.latitude

                print("longitude = \(longitude)")
                print("latitude = \(latitude)")
    }
```